# Best way to generate deadlines for milestones from template for different users in django

Tags: python, django

I want to generate the list of various milestones to accomplish something, and the deadline for each of them is calculated dynamically from a final date given by the user.

I'm not sure about the best way to handle this. The first idea that came to my mind is to write some <strike>template</strike> (not django template here) file on the server containing the necessary informations for generating all the steps, which will be fetched once for every new user, and used to create a list of milestone objects from a milestone class (some generic model in django). Maybe something written in json :

```
{"some_step":
  {
  "start_date" = "final_date-10",
  "end_date" = "final_date-7",
  }
}
```

and the corresponding model

```
class Milestone(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def time_to_final(self,time):
        return self.final_date-time
```

strings like the "finaldate-10" would be converted by some routine and passed at the registration time to the time_to_final method, when initializing the data for the new user in the database.

However I'm not sure it's the best approach. Though it won't be used by millions of people, I'm worried about possible negative impacts on the server performances ? Is there a better, maybe more pythonic way ?

**EDIT for more clarification :**

A user wants to do complete something at date D0.

My app generates the steps like this :

- do step 1 from date D1i to date D1f
- do step 2 from date D2i to date D2f
  -...
- until date D0 is reached and all tasks are completed

All the dates are calculated when D0 is provided.
All the steps are generated for every user.

Answer (score 2):

What have templates got to do with this?  Design your models first - maybe you need a `Steps` model with a foreign key to `User` and a foreign Key to `Milestone` (or maybe not - I'm not clear from your description).

Only when you've got the data clear in your mind start thinking about templates etc.

The great thing about django is that once you've made your models you can use the admin interface to enter some data. It will quickly become clear whether you've modeled your problem correctly.

Don't worry about performance, get your data structures clear, make it work and if you find it isn't running fast enough (unlikely) optimize it.

Comment: My bad, I had a hard time finding a correct word to define what I want to do, and at some point, template sounded good, and it didn't came to my mind that it could conflict with the django template system.

Actually what I meant is that the milestones and steps are the same for everybody, the only variable parameter is the final date, which is used to calculate the various dates in the template or canvas or call it like you want ! And for each user, I want to generate the whole thing in the database from django.